# How can I find the subject matter of a question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

If I were to have a question like
`Why Is Raiden Punching Armstrong So Fascinating?`, how could I get the subject matter of the question (`Raiden Punching Armstrong`) programmatically using Python? Using `spacy` to tokenize the sentence yields the following:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sentence = "Why Is Raiden Punching Armstrong So Fascinating?"
nlp_doc=nlp(sentence)
subject = [tok.dep_ for tok in nlp_doc]
print(subject) 
# ['advmod', 'ROOT', 'compound', 'compound', 'nsubj', 'advmod', 'nsubj', 'punct']
```

Apologies if my question seems to be too general.

Comment: How would you do it as a person?  What is preventing you from translating that into Python?

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't know which library to use and how I should use it

Comment: How would you do it as a person?

Comment: @ScottHunter I would take the sentence into context and find the subjects. Why?

Comment: Because that's what you want to implement, and given how under-defined that is, good luck programming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is the noun that is doing or being something. The verb is carrying out the action or linking the subject to further information. And the direct object is receiving the action of the verb.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sentence = "Why Is Raiden Punching Armstrong So Fascinating?"
nlp_doc=nlp(sentence)

#I am taking propernoun, other nouns if any, and verb in the subject. It depends upon your sentence; we may skip the verb part in the subject.

for x in nlp_doc :
#here pos_ keyword is used for Parts Of Speech
if x.pos_ == "PROPN" or x.pos_ == "NOUN" or x.pos_ == "VERB":
  print(x, end=' ')

#output
Raiden Punching Armstrong
```